# text file stream reader in windows xp reads only limited number of lines

Tags: c#, vb.net, text, windows-xp

I have a visual basic (even c# help would be nice) app that reads a text file containing 16000 lines from the web then converts them to a string array.
It works perfectly on windows 7 and later and all lines are read.
But on windows XP, in an odd way only 5694 lines of the file are read and any line after that is neglected

```
  Private Sub buildWordList()
    Try
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead("www.example.com/myfile.txt"))
        Dim line As String = ""
        Dim myCounter As Integer = 0
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                                FileIO.TextFieldParser(reader)
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters("|")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                myCounter = myCounter + 1
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                For i As Integer = 1 To 100
                    If currentRow(0).ToString() = i.ToString() Then
                        magList(i).Add(currentRow(1).ToString())
                    End If
                Next
            End While
            MsgBox(myCounter)
        End Using
    Catch ex As WebException
        MsgBox("not internet")
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
End Sub
```

p.s. I created myCounter to know how many lines are read in both XP and 7, in win 7 all 16000 lines are read and in win XP as I mentioned only 5694 lines are read

I don't know if that is a limit in windows XP or what, please help !!